# How to dynamically build a class in java

Tags: java

All:

I am pretty new in Java. What I want to do is build a java data model object dynamically according to the CSV fields it reads in, like:

**file1.csv**

```
Name, Age, Email, Url
Allen, 30, allen@mail.com, http://allen.mail.com
Bob, 20, bob@mail.com, http://bob.mail.com
```

Firstly I read in the header, and **according to the header**, I want to create a class InfoModel which **has those field names as its member variable**.

Could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could create the sourcecode dynamically, compile and load the class using the java API. But it would be pretty complicated to use the resulting class. You should simply use a hashmap for the variables in InfoModel and create the class before runtime. Would be simpler to use and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a corresponding `Bean Class` having **Name, Age, Email, Url** as member variable

```
Class Employee{

private String name;
private String age;
private String email;
private String url;

    public Employee(String name,String age,String email,String url){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    //and so on

    }

// their getters and setters
}

    // their getters and setters
    }
```

Now as soon as you read the CSV lines after header , you can create Object of Employee Class

```
new Employee(name,age,email,url);
```

Comment: Thanks though, I guess it is my fault for not clearly expressing my question: My question is how to dynamically build CLASS(the Emplyee in your answer) according to diff structures of csv file during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is build a java data model object dynamically according to the CSV fields it reads in.

Ok, let's look at the CSV input again.

```
Name, Age, Email, Url
Allen, 30, allen@mail.com, http://allen.mail.com
Bob, 20, bob@mail.com, http://bob.mail.com
```

Here's the class that you want to generate.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

public class InfoModel {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final String email;
    private final String url;

    public InfoModel(String name, int age, String email, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

}
```

So, here is the main question you have to answer to generate the text of this class from the CSV file.

How do I determine what type of data is in the CSV file?  In other words, how do I determine that Age is an int?  How do I determine that Name is a String?

Once you've figured out the data types, you can output the text of the InfoModel class by using a lot of StringBuilders.

See my article, [Writing Java Code that Writes Java Code](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=407), for an example of how to write a Java application that writes Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea... If the fields are limited, for example if you only need various combinations of fields, you could create an interface for each field (getter and setter) and then creaty a [Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) object for all of them, handling the data, for example, with an internal HashMap. This will get you an object that implements all of the interfaces, but of course, only in a very specific way.

Comment: Then, of course, you could use a single implementation, and just return `null` if the `get`ted column wasn't there.

Comment: Also true. I really cannot see WHY anyone would want such a data class at Runtime. You can't do much with it, anyway... *shrug*